# How to recognize if HealthKit permissions have been turned off after turning on initially?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, watchkit

If initially the user gives permission to HealthKit as required from `applicationShouldRequestHealthAuthorization` AppDelegate initiated from the WatchOS. Later on like after a few days if the user decides to turn off permissions on the iOS end, what would be the ideal way to recognize this on the WatchOS end apart from getting no streaming data? Thank you.